# Matplotlib: impose personalized colorbar

Tags: matplotlib

#### background story:

I am producing two plots. One plot is a standard scatterplot with color map. The other plot contains multiple histograms, each histogram has a different color that is mapped to the colormap of the previous plot. I now want to show the colormap of the previous plot in this new plot. Here is a snippet of code:

```
#plot 1
f1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
sc = ax1.scatter(x, y, c=z)
cb = f1.colorbar(sc)
f1.show()

#plot 2
f2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
h1 = ax2.hist(x1, color=cb.to_rgba(val1))
h2 = ax2.hist(x2, color=cb.to_rgba(val2))
h3 = ax2.hist(x3, color=cb.to_rgba(val3))
```

Now I would like to add cb (from the `f1` plot) to this new plot. Something like `f2.set_colorbar(cb)` does not exists.

#### Question

Given a plot generated with `f2, ax2 = plt.subplots()` and given a colorbar, how can I force matplotlib to insert a given colorbar in this  plot? Note that the colorbar does not need to be related to the data inside the plot

Comment: Why is `cb2 = f2.colorbar(sc)` not an option?

Comment: I tried and it works! I haven't tried it because I didn't thought I could pass a plot of `f1` into a function of the figure `f2`. Thanks. If you want you can post as an answer.

Comment: Sometimes you learn more by trying things out and making mistakes. While in principle you are correct that you cannot have the same artist in two figures at once, here you are not putting the scatter itself to the new axes, but instead `f2.colorbar(sc)` will create a new axes with it's own artists based on the properties of the scatter.

Comment: Thanks for the life lesson sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply add another colorbar to the second figure based on the `PathCollection` of the first figure's scatter plot.

```
f1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
sc = ax1.scatter(x, y, c=z)
cb = f1.colorbar(sc)
f1.show()

#plot 2
f2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
cb2 = f2.colorbar(sc)
```